# Git undo previous merge which is preventing diff

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-merge, git-branch

So this is my situation:

Say I was on branch A. I first did `git checkout -b B` to create a new branch B off A. I then did some work on B (e.g. 5 commits). I then went back onto A and did some work (e.g. 3 commits). Then I wanted that work to be reflected on B, so I switched to B and I did `git merge A`. I then continued working on branch B (e.g. 5 more commits).

Now Im finished I want to merge B into A, however, on gitlab when doing a merge request diff I can only compare branch B to master and not A (im assuming this is because of the merge). How do I somehow remedy this so these branches are no longer considered merged even though they were previously merged? thanks

Comment: Edit your merge request, and change it target branch to `A`.

Comment: That's item 4 in [the doc to creating a new Merge Request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/creating_merge_requests.html#from-the-merge-request-list) (there is no screen capture, though), and it can also be edited on an existing merge request.

Comment: EDIT: So turns out my target branch was set to master which was the default, changing to A fixed this

Comment: Given that you could simply merge A into B locally, was there a reason why you couldn't just check out A, then merge B back into it, also locally?

Answer (score 0):

So turns out my target branch was set to master which was the default, changing to A fixed this